# Add user in group with permission problem

Tags: powershell, permissions, groups

In my site, I add user with powershell to a group.

```
Set-SPUser -Identity $User -Web $siteCollUrl -Group $group
```

The user appear in the groupe but when I do a "check permission" on the SharePoint site, there is no result...

Comment: Does the group have permissions?

Comment: What is the group you're adding the user?
The group you add user into has any permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the group does not have any permission, run this to get the permission for the group:

```
    $urlWeb = "http://yourPortalUrl"
    $web = Get-SpWeb $urlWeb
    foreach($roleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments)
    {
         write-host -foregroundcolor green "Group Name: "$roleAssignment.Member.Name "..."
         foreach($roleDefinition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
         {
              write-host -foregroundcolor red "Permission Name: "$roleDefinition.Name "..."
         }
    }
```

and this to get a complete permission report by user:

```
$urlWeb = "http://sp2010"
Get-SPUser -Web $urlWeb | select UserLogin, @{name=”Exlicit given roles”;expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name=”Roles given via groups”;expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}},Groups | format-Table -auto
```

[How to get user permissions report by using Powershell](http://www.spstech.net/sp2010/how-to-get-user-permissions-report-by-using-powershell/)